# Google cloud talent with react native

Tags: react-native, api, google-cloud-talent-solution

How to get list of job from google talent-solution in react native?

I have also refer this : https://cloud.google.com/solutions/talent-solution

Comment: Have you referred [this](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/samples/job-search-list-jobs#job_search_list_jobs-nodejs) Cloud Talent documentation?